Docusign Envelopes API text tabs are linked (not unique)
"textTabs" : [
    {"anchorString" : "***TBx_1.7***",
     "anchorXOffset" : "0",
     "anchorYOffset" : "-5",
     "conditionalParentLabel" : "theConditional_0",
     "conditionalParentValue" : "on",
     "width" : "250" },
    {"anchorString" : "***TBx_2.7***",
     "anchorXOffset" : "0",
     "anchorYOffset" : "-5",
     "conditionalParentLabel" : "theConditional_5",
     "conditionalParentValue" : "on",
     "width" : "250" }
   ]

Hey y'all.
I'm using the DocuSign API to try and get a number of text tabs to display and accept input individually.   The desired behavior is that each text field should the contain a unique value.  Currently, I'm getting the same value across all text tabs, which are defined in the JSON above.  In other words, I type XYZ into the first text field and it writes XYZ into both.  I want them to act independently.
***CBx_1.7*** ***TBx_1.7***
***CBx_2.7*** ***TBx_2.7***

Also double checked the tags in the underlying document and they're correct.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

figured it out.  the text tabs need a tabLabel.

The tabLabel element in text tabs is used to group them together. This means that if you don't set it, they have the same empty value. When two tabs have the same value for their tabLabel element, the system assumes you want them to be the same. This can be useful in some situations. For example, you provide a value on the first and last page and want it to be the same, but don't want to force signers to scroll many pages if they change the value in one place.
By putting unique tabLabel values you ensure that the text will be different on each tab.
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-tab-types
